# Animating along a curve using Javascript & simple math

Tags: javascript, html, animation, bezier, curve

I feel like the solution is very simple, but in all honestly I failed math multiple times in high school, so I'm barely grasping even the basic concepts right now.

The idea is very simple.. I want to have a bunch of graphical objects tween animate from one side of a 300x300px div to the other side along randomized curved paths as if they were being tossed or dropped from the top left to the bottom right (and vice versa, back and forth).

I know I need to use some form of Trigonometry to solve this (sin, cos, tan??). I also already know how to get my two points (randomizing Y points, and then randomly putting x points on the positive or negative side of the 300px width). But the part where I have to actually calculate steps along a curve is beyond me.

Here's a crappy diagram of basically what I'm attempting.. I searched Google but all of the examples were way overcomplicated or too abstract. I just want to learn how to make a curve between two points.. That's it!

[image: crappy diagram of what I'm attempting]

So simple question: How do I randomize a curved animation (or plot points along a curve) between two points using vanilla JavaScript (no JQuery please).

Comment: Find the description for your path, first. Then animating along the path is literally based on evaluating the functions. Sin, cos? Maybe. Bezier curves? Maybe. Random position tables? Maybe. As for the "no jquery", sure but don't ignore pathing library like tween.js or d3.js, this is a thing they do (that said, this is indeed simple enough to just be doable in a few lines of JS and a canvas)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you would like a quick look into the math of JavaScript animations , you might consider visiting this [link](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/quick-look-math-animations-javascript/)

Comment: I see that the link will tell you about a very similar person that was very bad at math, but is going to give you a quick look

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you only need very simple trigonometry (sine and cosine). If you are tossing something from a point (X0, Y0), the equations of motion are more like a parabolic trajectory.

From Wikipedia:

> Displacement and coordinates of parabolic throwing
>
> At any time t, the projectile's horizontal and vertical displacement
>   are:
>
> ```
> x = X0 + v0 * t * cos(theta)
> y = Y0 + v0 * t * sin(theta) − 0.5 * g * t * t
> ```

So there you go, your coordinates in pixels for every t time step.
You may define theta and v0 as constants or also as random values to make the animation more chaotic and lively.
Play with the value of g (in Earth it is 9.8 m/s²), because probably when scaling to pixels/s² it might overshoot.
Also you may want to give negative values to X0 and Y0 in order to intercept the descending part of the trajectories, leaving the ascending out of the div.

Comment: This is great, but I'm still not sure how to use it, can you help me understand the pieces of this equation? what does v0 represent? velocity? What kind of number would I use for that? 1 or 10 or 0.5? What kind of value would I use for t? seconds? milliseconds? How do I know/set the total length of time of the trajectory? g is gravity? Do I set that to 9.8 to simulate earth gravity? why is time being multiplied twice at the end? What is theta? how does someone use theta in these sorts of equations? How do I set theta? Thanks so much for this!

Comment: V0 represents initial velocity, indeed in your case in pixels/second. I would start with 10 and then see how it matches your simulation.

Comment: T should be in seconds also for the sake of consistency. The total time length of the trajectories is something that you will adjust once you have a feeling of it. g is a constant, that you can start leaving as 9.8. Time is multiplied twice because it is time squared (t*t = t²). Theta can be 45 (of pi/2 depending on the math library you are using) to begin with, but for different graphical objects you can have different angles.

Comment: Hi Rabindranath, thank you for the help! I setup a codepen to demonstrate where I'm at.. I can't seem to get the ball to jump properly with your equation. When I remove " - 0.5 * g * t * t " the ball moves in a straight diagonal line. https://codepen.io/cmaxster/pen/XgvqGN What do you think? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Hi Chad, in your code I can only see the error of inputting the angle in degrees, rather than in radians (replace Math.cos(theta) with Math.cos(theta/180*Math.PI)). However, that doesn't totally resolve the issue. I would just pull out the values from the console for tickCount, ball.x and ball.y and try to visualize with some more context in a spreadsheet. I think that your only issue is in the scale, transforming from m/s to pixels/ms. A segment of a parable can seem a straight line when looked at from very close. Tweak t and g until they fit in your screen =).